# How to collect user and billing email address at same time?

Tags: civicontribute, profile, email

I have a scenario where I am creating a membership form for minors, which is filled in by their parents. Therefore, I need to collect a 'billing' e-mail address which is different from the minor's e-mail address.

When I create a profile with an additional 'billing e-mail address' field in, it doesn't actually show up in the form.

Any ideas what I'm doing on? (using Civi for Wordpress)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment contribution pages don't allow additional email addresses (they get stripped out). [There is an open issue in JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16339) but I believe it needs funding.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's not an option for you because you're on Wordpress, but for others who may encounter this issue, this is an excellent use case for the [Webform CiviCRM Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module for CiviCRM users on Drupal.